# Mediaelement.js 'loadedmetadata' event always returns duration 0 for Facebook videos

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

For Facebook (and dailymotion) videos, the loadedmetadata event does not contain the duration of the video

```
...
success: function(me, node) {
  me.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function _loaded_src(e) {
    console.log(me.duration)
  })
},
...
```

Duration is always 0

I have tried all other events listed in the documentation

I have tried calling play/pause then checking the duration but it still comes back 0

After some amount of time the duration is figured out, does anyone know  how I could wait for the duration to be available?